# I get an error when loading an url from a tutorial from where I just copied it

Tags: python, json, api

Is it because of the url being nonexistent anymore?

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/"
             "allcurrencies/quote?format=json") as response:
    source = response.read()

print(source)
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Please learn to format your code -> [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: It's because the page you're looking for isn't here (i.e. the URL is invalid). Note that when posting questions here, always show or mention what the error message was.

Comment: Did you consider entering that URL into a browser to see what happens?